The problem of footnote numbers (MSword) by numbering restart each page
A few days ago, I updated Office and then I had a problem
All the numbers of the footnotes in the renumbering of restart each page
each page the numbers of the footnote are number 8, while when I make it continuous or change it to concluding, the numbers are correct and continuous.
Please advise me

When, I chose the continuous of the footnote, numbers are ok
